# How do I set up Foursquare for alerts?

Tags: 8.0, foursquare

From what I've gathered, Foursquare allows you to toggle a per-friend "pings" option so that you get notified whenever certain friends check in. However, I've yet to see this work. I have pings turned on for my wife, but I never get an alert from my phone when she checks in anywhere.

I've checked Background Tasks, and Foursquare isn't even in there - as if there isn't even a service available for it to run in the background. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

The official Foursquare app does not provide alerts as push notifications. They simple did not implement that feature.

I'm using [4th&Mayor](http://www.4thandmayor.com/) for Foursquare and it has an option to do this push notifications. Maybe you can give a try.

You need to know that it provides push notifications based on user usage so maybe you need to read [this](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/05/favoring-active-users-for-tiles-and-processing/) article before.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. The tiering system seems a bit more complex than its worth though. It would be nice if there was just a $5 premium version of the app that got all services instead.

Comment: +1 for 4th & Mayor. IMO much better and snappier than the official Foursquare app. Not affiliated, just a satisfied user.